# Bigbluebutton - Default Presentation/Uploaded Presentation not working

Tags: bigbluebutton

I'm using BBB version 2.2.15 on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm facing issue with default presentation is not working.

I have default.pdf in `/var/www/bigbluebutton-default/default.pdf` as well. I could also see PDF getting uploaded in `/var/bigbluebutton` as well.

Answer (score 1):

this issue happened after September,2021.
technical details is available in [this link.](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/)
you can use another SSL provider or its better to replace BBB2.2.15 with BBB2.3 or BBB2.4

Answer (score 0):

have you configured IPv6 correctly? I had the same problem because I hadn't entered IPv6 in the DNS settings.

In the DNS records, your domain must point to IPv4 and also to IPv6!