# BigBlueButton fails to upload presentation

Tags: bigbluebutton

I'm using BBB version 1:2.2.0-5 on Ubuntu version 16.04, and from one day to another it suddenly fails to upload a presentation. I already tried doing `sudo bbb-conf --restart` but nothing. I also tried converting the bigbluebutton.properties with `native2ascii` but it actually got worse.

This is the error stack:

```
/var/log/bigbluebutton/bbb-web.2021-09-20.log:2021-09-20T11:04:44.023Z ERROR o.b.p.PresentationUrlDownloadService - Invalid HTTP response=[404] for url=[https://oururl.com/pluginfile.php/271/mod_bigbluebuttonbn/presentation/9abaa22d7f3d68363ce60a45d377edbf/Webinar%20day%201.pdf] with meeting[f4f40140c33569b0f7baa997c70d5a9a0cce5507-1632222283626]
/var/log/bigbluebutton/bbb-web.2021-09-20.log:2021-09-20T11:04:44.023Z ERROR o.b.web.controllers.ApiController - Failed to download presentation=[https://oururl.com/pluginfile.php/271/mod_bigbluebuttonbn/presentation/9abaa22d7f3d68363ce60a45d377edbf/Webinar%20day%201.pdf], meeting=[f4f40140c33569b0f7baa997c70d5a9a0cce5507-1632222283626], fileName=[null]
/var/log/bigbluebutton/bbb-web.2021-09-20.log:2021-09-20T11:04:49.024Z ERROR o.b.p.DocumentConversionServiceImp - Presentation upload failed for meetingId=f4f40140c33569b0f7baa997c70d5a1a0cce5507-1632135883626 presId=1de6396319933dd1ea4a0d5967dbf2dc8decb8c6-1632135883803
/var/log/bigbluebutton/bbb-web.2021-09-20.log:2021-09-20T11:04:49.025Z ERROR o.b.p.DocumentConversionServiceImp - Presentation upload fail reasons [failed_to_download_file]
/var/log/bigbluebutton/bbb-web.2021-09-20.log:2021-09-20T22:44:59.599Z ERROR o.b.p.h.PdfPageCounterHandler - Exception counting images
/var/log/bigbluebutton/bbb-web.2021-09-20.log:2021-09-20T22:44:59.699Z ERROR o.b.p.imp.PresentationFileProcessor -  --analytics-- data={"filename":"Webinar%20day%201.pdf","logCode":"determine_num_pages_failed","meetingId":"f4f20140c33569b0f7baa997c70d5a9a0cce5507-1632177893862","message":"Failed to determine number of pages.","podId":"DEFAULT_PRESENTATION_POD","presId":"1de6336319933dd4ea4a0d5967dbf2dc8decb8c6-1632177894042"}
/var/log/bigbluebutton/bbb-web.2021-09-21.log:2021-09-21T07:11:55.754Z ERROR o.b.p.h.PdfPageCounterHandler - Exception counting images
/var/log/bigbluebutton/bbb-web.2021-09-21.log:2021-09-21T07:11:55.754Z ERROR o.b.p.imp.PresentationFileProcessor -  --analytics-- data={"filename":"Webinar%20day%201.pdf","logCode":"determine_num_pages_failed","meetingId":"f4f40440c33569b0f7baa997c70d5a9a0cce5507-1632208310241","message":"Failed to determine number of pages.","podId":"DEFAULT_PRESENTATION_POD","presId":"1de6398319933dd4ea4a0d5967dbf2dc8decb8c6-1632208310408"}
  -- ERRORS found in /var/log/bigbluebutton/* -- 
/var/log/bigbluebutton/bbb-web.2021-09-20.log:2021-09-20T22:44:59.599Z ERROR o.b.p.h.PdfPageCounterHandler - Exception counting images
/var/log/bigbluebutton/bbb-web.2021-09-20.log:java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
/var/log/bigbluebutton/bbb-web.2021-09-20.log:org.bigbluebutton.presentation.imp.CountingPageException: Exception while trying to determine number of pages.
/var/log/bigbluebutton/bbb-web.2021-09-21.log:2021-09-21T07:11:55.754Z ERROR o.b.p.h.PdfPageCounterHandler - Exception counting images
/var/log/bigbluebutton/bbb-web.2021-09-21.log:java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
/var/log/bigbluebutton/bbb-web.2021-09-21.log:org.bigbluebutton.presentation.imp.CountingPageException: Exception while trying to determine number of pages.
```

I changed the Url and IDs for security reasons. For now, the teachers are sharing their screen as a workaround.

Comment: seems from the stack trace "https://oururl.com/pluginfile.php/271/" you are using the moodle plugin is this correct?  Also current stable bbb version approx 2.3.4 on ubuntu 18, so your version you have listed  1:2.2.0-5 is really old or its a version for something else. I am not familiar with moodle/bbb. I was able to find your error reported here as a bug https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/CONTRIB-8538

Comment: Why don't you use the latest version?

Comment: I described cause if issue here.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70016627/bigbluebutton-default-presentation-uploaded-presentation-not-working/70052072#70052072)